# Creation of WindowsAzure.Management certificate on server side

Tags: c#, azure

1. Certificate in Base64, getting through the command Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile in Azure PowerShell (no custom certificates in Azure/Settings/Management Certificates do not add)
2. Create a certificate:

   Byte[] certificate = Convert.FromBase64String(AzureData.Base64AzureManagementCertificate);

where AzureData.Base64AzureManagementCertificate - resource file

```
X509Cer = new X509Certificate2 (certificate, String.Empty, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

Locally run project, everything works fine.

After Publishing, X509Certificate2(...) in an error:
"The system can not find the file specified"

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you running this code in an Azure Website?

Comment: Yes, on the side of the Azure Website

Comment: Please see this blog post on using Certificates in an Azure Website: https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/27/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/. HTH.

Comment: Thank you very much, the article was very helpful, but it is not a complete solution, See below.

Answer (score 1):

Do everything according to the article:
https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/27/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/

But (3. Access from app)

We must also add the certificate .cer to Azure/Settings/Management Certificates
Then initialize the certificate:

```
new X509Certificate2(certificate, "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

where certificate .pfx file, password - to PFX